# Can't access local API with React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm able to access the API on emulator's browser, but not in the app.

I tried using localhost, 10.0.2.2 and IPV4 already. With localhost and 10.0.2.2 it returns NETWORK ERROR immediately, but using IPV4 it takes some time to give the error.

It's a fresh new react native app and a simple web API with C#.